# Can I parallelize my build when linking against multiple interdependent static libraries?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've built my app as a workspace containing one project with an app binary target and many projects containing static library targets. My app target links against all the static libraries. Some of my static libraries depend on each other, and I handle this by ordering the targets built in my scheme so that all dependencies are built before the libraries that depend on them.

What I'd like to accomplish is to use the 'Parallelize Build' feature to speed up building my app scheme. However I need to ensure that my static libraries are built with respect to their dependencies. It doesn't seem like I can set 'Target Dependencies' between these static library targets because they are not all in the same project (Is this the case or am I misunderstanding how this works? Is it possible to have cross project target dependencies)?

Is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks for any information!

Answer (score 1):

After some research it does seem like the only way to get this working is to set up my app using nested subprojects instead of a workspace (so that I can create target dependencies between my dependent libraries). I'd love to be corrected on this point if anyone knows another way!